# Dump of process in crash/quit time for gdb import?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, crash-dumps

I have C++ software (server) and its crashing, i don't know exactly
where problem is based on logs. I want make something that linux after
crash or quit do dump of that process that i will someway import that this
file to `gdb` and analyze what is doing what not should.

Anyone do something in past?
Can someone help me with some informations ideas or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a regular core dump which works with GDB to find the crash location. 
See http://linux.die.net/man/5/core for information.

If the daemon does not have write permission where the current directory is, no core will be generated. To redirect it, try;

```
mkdir /tmp/corefiles 
chmod 777 /tmp/corefiles 
echo "/tmp/corefiles/core" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Comment: If you have the source code of your daemon, compiling them with `-g -Wall` flags to the `gcc` compiler is helpful.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Boths flags are present in Makefile

Comment: Then get the core and debug it with `gdb  /path/to/daemon core`

Comment: You need the daemon to crash to get the core dumped... But you need to be sure that the core size limit is big enough.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a core file?  In the script that launches your daemon, add this command (assuming the interpreter for the script is `bash`):

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

That set the maximum size of a core file to "unlimited" (it's usually 0 by default).

Comment: technically this is not a daemon, this is console application in screen, this makes difference? i have setted to unlimited this but dont have core file.

Comment: If you're running from the console, then just launch it in gdb.

Comment: Can't, this application must stay alive always, it running in bash while, when it crash then it starting again when i attach gdb then gdb will not let process die until i exit gdb, i can't afford that in any way

Comment: The core is by default written to the current directory, so the user starting the program must have write permissions to that directory.

Comment: Nice point. but user on what program works in current directory have `rwx`.

Comment: Why must always the daemon stay alive?  Are you try to debug a crash on a system in production?

Answer (score 1):

As others replied, you can get a core dump file. Be sure to configure your environment appropriately.

Another way, once the daemon is already running and before it crashes, is to [attach](http://private.nmr.ru/manuals/gdb/gdb_23.html) it thru the debugger.

And you can also start your daemon with `gdb --args` */path/to/daemon*  *daemon-arguments* ...

Comment: Thanks, but is not applicable for me, i can't attach to this because then process after crash will not release binded ports and new deamon will not start in place of other and this application must stay alive always.